# Demora para a resposta da consulta do MYSQL

Tags: node.js, typescript

Estou com um problema que busco solução mas acredito que eu posso não estar implementando corretamente.
Tenho uma consulta ao mysql que me retorna ramais, essa função deve me retornar para outra classe assim salvando em uma variável.
Mas a resposta demora me retornar assim ele retorna o valor vazio só depois das condições que deveria fazer com esse valor ele me retorna o valor da consulta.
Acredito que deve ser feita uma configuração de async/await mas não consegui fazer corretamente.
É um servidor backend NodeJS utilizando typescript.
Poderiam me ajudar?

Consulta ao banco de dados:

```
class MsqlRequests {

public static Ramais()
{
    var ResultadoJSON
    var array = []
     Mysql.getConnection((error, conn) => {
        if (error) { return response.status(500).send({ error: error }) }
        conn.query(
            'SELECT ativo, ramal FROM ramais;',
            (error, resultado, fields) => {
                conn.release();
                if (error) { return response.status(500).send({ error: error }) }
                ResultadoJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(resultado));
                ResultadoJSON.map(function(item){
                    array.push(item)
                   })

                   console.log("array 1")
                   console.log(array)
                   return array
            }
        )
    })
    console.log("array 2")
    console.log(array)
    return array
    
}
```

Onde realizo a chamada:

```
export class Controller {

public async efetuarReducao(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {

    var obj = {
        relatorio1: [],
        relatorioRamais: []
    };

    console.log("Ramais da função")
    obj.relatorio1.push(MsqlRequests.Ramais()) // Chamo a função de consulta MSQL e preciso salvar em obj.relatorio1

    obj.relatorio.map(reduzir);

    function OndeRealizoAsCondicoes(elemento) {
}

 res.json(obj)


    }

}
```

Comment: Na classe `Ramais`, o `Mysql.getConnection` não deveria estar um `await` antes?

Comment: Vagner tentei colocar o await mas não foi quando implementei o callback deu certo.
Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementei o callback e foi resolvido.

```
import { Request, response, Response } from 'express'

const Mysql = require('../../database/MsqlConnection').pool;

class MsqlRequests {

  public static Ramais(callback: (array) => void) {

    var ResultadoJSON
    const array = []
    Mysql.getConnection((error, conn) => {
        if (error) { return (response.status(500).send({ error: error })) }
        conn.query(
            'SELECT ativo, ramal FROM ramais;',
            (error, resultado, fields) => {
                conn.release();
                if (error) { return (response.status(500).send({ error: error })) }
                ResultadoJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(resultado));
                ResultadoJSON.map(function (item) {
                    array.push(item)
                })
                return callback(array);
            }
        )
    })
  }
}


export default MsqlRequests
```

Chamada:

```
var array;

export class Controller {

public async efetuarReducao(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {

var obj = {
    relatorio1: [],
    relatorioRamais: []
};

    array = MsqlRequests.Ramais(function (array2) {

        array2.map(function (item) {
            obj.relatorioRamais.push(item)
        })
        obj.relatorioRamais.map(OndeRealizoAsCondicoes);

        res.send(obj)

    }

function OndeRealizoAsCondicoes(elemento) {

/*Realizo condicoes */

}
}

}
```